# How do I watch Amazon Prime videos on the MacBook Pro M2?

Tags: macos, video

There has got to be a reason why I cannot watch Amazon Prime videos on the MacBook Pro M2, because I can watch them on my non-M2 MacBooks. Anybody know what makes the M2 so special that I cannot do what millions of people do on all their MacBooks which is watch Amazon Prime videos?

I am on a MacBook Pro M2, Ventura MacOS: 13.5

I am using the Chrome browser version 122.0.6261.57, but this is also happening on the Safari browser that came with the MacBook and it also happens when I download the Amazon Prime client from the App store.

I do not get any error message, the video plays, but it acts as audio, so there is audio, but no video, the video is just a black screen although I am able to see the part where it shares that the film is NR, Not Rated, but then when it goes into the presentation of the show, a black screen.

Comment: I’m able to watch them from my M2 Air. Can you edit in what you’re seeing as a specific error condition or list your exact version of browser and macOS? (It may just be happening to you, but some detail will help us think of next steps together)

Comment: @bmike, Thank you, I have added the MacOS and browser versions.

Comment: try clearing your cache and enabling Adobe Flash or Javascript

Comment: @Ruskes Adobe Flash?

Comment: Do you get an error if you access Prime?

Comment: What ***exactly*** happens when you try? Blank screen, error message....? Any special network configuration, like a proxy? Any reason you're not updating to Sonoma?

Comment: @Ruskes Flash has been dead since January 2021.

Comment: @benwiggy did not know that. What was the cause of the death ?

Comment: @Ruskes It was rubbish. ;-) Security problems and excessive CPU use left Adobe no option but to kill it.